# "@" users on my django project

Tags: django, instagram

Just a quick question.

How can I implement the "@" feature used on most social networks on my django project. for example, @ludipie(ludipie being a username) should link to ludipie's profile page when clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You can set this in your templates

```
<a href="{{ request.user.profile.absolute_url }}">@{{request.user.username}}</a>
```

So basically you need to write `absolute_url` method which will return url to user page.

An example of this method could be

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('accounts:profile_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```